# Check All Elements for String

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to check if my array class has the string "Unavailable" contained for all elements:

```
classApplicantNDatesCount[] applicantCounts = null;  
....
...
applicantCounts = appCount.ToArray();
```

Specifically this "part" of the array I need to search through:

```
 applicantCounts[i].NadraDateAvailableforApplicant = "All Requested Slots UnAvailable"
```

So I need to check if all of `applicantCounts[i].NadraDateAvailableforApplicant` elements contains the string "Unavailable".

I have looked into `Array.TrueforAll` but not found a way to apply it to my situtation.

Apologies I don't think Im using the correct terminology which might make this slightly unclear.....

Comment: If that answer and/or the LINQ version of the same aren't working for you, it's because your question isn't clear - they both provide the code, verbatim, that solves what seems to be your problem. Can you provide a detailed example of input that satisfies your criteria and data that doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

LINQ eats this sort of thing for breakfast:

```
applicantCounts.All(a => a.NadraDateAvailableforApplicant.Contains("Unavailable"))
```

We're using [`.All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) here to check if a condition is true for all elements of an enumerable.

Note you have a capitalization typo in the string search.

Comment: Might be worth lower casing for a more robust search

Comment: Half hour searching google / half hour trying and retrying failed code / Answered on Stackoverflow in 5mins great stuff never lets you down

Answer (score 2):

Using `Array.TrueForAll` would look like this:

```
bool all = Array.TrueForAll(
  applicantCounts,
  x => x.NadraDateAvailableforApplicant.Contains("Unavailable")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As for @Benjamin's approach, i would use `IndexOf` instead of `Contains` where you can specify a `StringComparison` in case you'd like a case insensitive search and or specify `CultureInfo`:

```
applicantCounts.All(app => app.NadraDateAvailableforApplicant.IndexOf("Unavailable", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```